# SWRevealViewController dismiss keyboard on swipe

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) in my app and I am having a problem. I have a textfield in a scene, if I swipe left when the keyboard is open, the menu appears but it does not dismiss the keyboard. How do I dismiss keyboard on left swipe?

I have tried

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but it does not work, I think because I am already using a panGestureRecognizer for revealViewcontroller i.e. `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];`

I am also using `UITapGestureRecognizer` but it only works for tap not for swipe.

Comment: see my answer hope that helps u ..

Comment: see i updated my answer check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think u need to use one of the delegate method in the app delegate there are so may delegate methods are there but u need do somthing like below

dont add any gestures

use this delegate in the `appDelegate`
delete all the macros begins with `#if` don`t need that

put a break-point in app delegate to this method
below delegate method celled each time `SWRevealViewController` moved or sliced ..

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
   // NSLog( @"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [self stringFromFrontViewPosition:position]);
   if(position == FrontViewPositionRight) //check the where to move 
   {
      UINavigationController *viewController = revealController.frontViewController;

     if([viewController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[FrontViewController class]])
       {
         [(FrontViewController *)viewController.visibleViewController dismissKeyboard]; //where this is the method declared in the FrontViewController.h file
      }

   }
}
```

there is one warning still it works put break point and check 
hope this helps u ...

in  `FrontViewController.h`

```
  -(void)dismissKeyboard; //add this
```

in the `FrontViewController.m`

```
 -(void)dismissKeyboard
 {
      if([self.textField isFirstResponder]) //check
         [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work for me.... It says `no visible @interface for FrontViewController declares the selector dismissKeyboard`.... do you know which is the first method gets called  when the side menu appears?

Comment: well Of course I added -(void)dismissKeyboard in .h file :) but I did not add the delegate... now the error is gone but the method never gets called :(... if its working for you then you must be doing something else.. Can you share your project please (just the example which works)?Thanks

Comment: oky did u removed the #if conditions ... ?  and also set delegate to  Appdelegate, if u are using demo project then it added to app delegate make sure that u added this line `  revealController.delegate = self; //add this line line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions``

Comment: yes the line ` revealController.delegate = self;` is there... which if condition should I remove

Comment: the macros that begins with #if

Comment: @Ali if u hav still problem come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49117/ios-help

Comment: Ohhhh yes.... I did not remove #if, that's why the delegate methods were not getting called.. Thank you soo very much.. You are a life saver...

Comment: Now I am setting the SWRevealViewcontrollerDelegate to each ViewController where I have text fields and dismiss the keyboard in  `didMoveToPosition` method. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50612/discussion-between-shan-and-ali)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I added `self.revealController.delegate = self;` to my View Controller which I used as Front View.And delegate method get called.

I used
 `- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position{}`
delegate method and I wrote `[textField endEditing:YES];` in this delegate method.

Also added `<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>` to my ViewController.h which is my Front View.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
[[[self revealViewController] view] endEditing:YES]
```

Add this in

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
```

or any other delegate method based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Please add the below code in SWRevealViewContoller.m in the method -(BOOL)_panGestureShouldBegin

[self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to replace the revealToggle: method by your custom method like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myMethod)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

And than in your method:

```
-(void)myMethod{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
SWRevealViewController *reveal = self.revealViewController;
[reveal revealToggleAnimated:YES];
}
```

It will surely work.

Comment: This is a great solution for me because my app structure is too complex to make the same thing happen with implementing delegate in AppDelegete. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

check current position of frontview and write code of hiding keyboard in if condition.

Comment: Can you please give an example, which method should I use ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `self.textField` is the current first responder? If you are try to resign the first responder in the `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate's method `– gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`

Obviously return YES in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the below method in

> SWRevealViewContoller.m

```
(IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self revealToggleAnimated:YES]; 
}
```