# SWRevealViewController with storyboard hiding keyboard when swiped

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

[SWRevealViewController dismiss keyboard on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011975/swrevealviewcontroller-dismiss-keyboard-on-swipe)

Problem is the same but this answers does not help me.

There are some solutions in the given link.For example I don't have any **#if** macros to delete and I get an error when I write **revealController.delegate = self;** in `AppDelegate.m`

And the delegate method below never get called.

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
//Never get called
}
```

I searched the Internet and did everything mentioned in the given link.

I am using `SWRevealViewController` **V 1.1.3 https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/releases**

The problem is: I have a `UITextField` inside a `ViewController` which behaves as a Front View.When I click on `UITextField`, keyboard shows up, then I swipe to see my `ViewController` which behaves as Rear View but keyboard is still there and I can't hide it.

How can I make it possible?

Comment: Solved: 
I added `self.revealController.delegate = self;` to my View Controller which I used as Front View.And delegate method get called.I used `- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position{}`
delegate method and I wrote `[textField endEditing:YES];` in this delegate method.

Comment: Also added `<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using willMove to position.........However it displays the keyboard when the Rear View controller pops up soon after the keyboard gets hidden..........

For me this worked perfectly....

```
func revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin(revealController: SWRevealViewController!) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```